# RCP exported EXE shows java console

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've created a very simple RCP application (essentially just a default view).

I then created a product file and Exported the product (as many online guides have demonstrated). However when I run the .exe file a java console is shown alongside my application splash screen. Is this normal behaviour? (I wasn't expecting a console to show as it's been exported/deployed).

Current research suggests I should:

- run with javaw.exe
- use another installer

Any further insight or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: No it is not normal behavior. What do you have specified in the Program Arguments section of the .product file (on the Launching tab)?

Comment: -os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog

Comment: Those options are normally in the 'Run > Run Configuration', they are not appropriate for the .product file.

Comment: oh, apologies it's simply '-consoleLog' in the product launching tab. It runs fine when in eclipse. Only after exporting the console shows a java console and splash screen. weird.

Comment: A java console or a terminal window? The java console is shown according to your JRE settings.

Comment: Java console. I'm using jdk1.7.0_51. Is there anyway of telling eclipse before exporting to hide the console during execution or do I need to configure eclipse to use javaw.exe instead of java.exe?

Comment: It is possible that the '-consoleLog' option forces the console to appear. Again this is not really useful for the RCP build.

Comment: That's fixed the issue, thank you @greg-449 . Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the .product file at the 'Program Arguments' (on the 'Launching' tab in the editor). Remove the '-consoleLog' argument.